# React Native Material Dropdown not working on expo

Tags: react-native, material-ui, expo

I am using react native and expo 4.4.4 and
"react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",

This library was picked from this [Npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-dropdown) and [Github Link](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown)

Just copy pasted the example usage code you have given...

Its showing below error  :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `react-native-material-dropdown` is supported in Expo.

Use [@react-native-community/picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/picker/) instead.